# MSACCESS Update Query with Join

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm having some issues making some adjustments to one of my tools with an update query. The original design didn't need an order status, but with reporting requests, the tool needs to be updated with the order status. I have tried adding in a LEFT JOIN based upon some online research and keep getting an error.

```
UPDATE TRAFFICDATABASE_Query

LEFT JOIN FactBP_Query ON TRAFFICDATABASE_Query.DELIVERY_NUMBER = 
FactBP_Query.DELIVERY_NUMBER 
SET TRAFFICDATABASE_Query.CARRIER_ID = UCASE([Forms]![Edit_PO]![CARRIER]), 
TRAFFICDATABASE_Query.COMMENTS = Forms!Edit_PO![COMMENTS], 
TRAFFICDATABASE_Query.CUSTOMER_CANCEL_DATE = [Forms]![Edit_PO]! 
[CUSTOMER_CANCEL_DATE], 
TRAFFICDATABASE_Query.TRAFFIC_SPECIALIST = [Forms]![Edit_PO]! 
[TRAFFIC_SPECIALIST], 
TRAFFICDATABASE_Query.RR_DATE = [Forms]![Edit_PO]![RR_DATE], 
TRAFFICDATABASE_Query.RA_DATE = [Forms]![Edit_PO]![RA_DATE], 
TRAFFICDATABASE_Query.PLANNED_SHIP_DATE = [Forms]![Edit_PO]! 
[PLANNED_SHIP_DATE], 
TRAFFICDATABASE_Query.CONFIRMATION_NUMBER = [Forms]![Edit_PO]! 
[CONFIRMATION_NUMBER], 
TRAFFICDATABASE_Query.WR_ID = [Forms]![Edit_PO]![WR_ID], 
TRAFFICDATABASE_Query.LAST_UPDATE = NOW()

WHERE ((([TRAFFICDATABASE_Query]![CUSTOMER_PURCHASE_ORDER_ID])=[Forms]! 
[Edit_PO]![CUSTOMER_PURCHASE_ORDER_ID_Title]) and 
(FactBP_Query.ORDER_STATUS <> 'Shipped'));
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: make code copy/paste-able :P

Comment: I have edited the original question.

Comment: Be _very_ careful with `UPDATE` in combination with a `LEFT JOIN` when using Access. This is rarely what you want, and will insert new values in the table if no matching row is found (in contrast to how other DBMSes handle joins in updates). It will also duplicate rows if there are multiple matching rows.

Comment: Updating a query is tricky business, even more so when it is made up of other queries which may also in turn be made up from other queries. It will 100% not work if any of the involved queries and sub-queries, on any level, has any kind of aggregation, or if you are trying to update a field that is used to link tables or queries.

Answer (score 0):

the generic Syntax for Access SQL Joins is as follows:

```
    UPDATE tbl1 
    INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.Column = tbl2.Column
    SET tbl2.OtherColumn = tbl2.OtherColumn;
```

And based on your on your query the issue is most likely what is in the FactBP_Query. There are tons of reasons why you'd get this error. Check this link https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/query/non-updateable/index.html Allen Brown also has an in depth article about it.

You can get around this by getting the Status column value via a subquery. I might even put that entire logic in to a sub query to be joined upon, but I have a feeling that it might be too complicated for Access to handle. Either way, you have options and you just have to experiment to find a work around.